# maven server-client project structure

Tags: java, maven, sockets

I'm gonna create a simple card game based on Java sockets so the client should be distributed. My concern is about that there are some common classes used by `server` and `client` like domain models. Should i create three maven submodules for each purposes like `cardgame-server, cardgame-client, cardgame-common`, is it really good solution?

Answer (score -1):

It's a common solution to this kind of problem. Or you can use three separate maven projects.

If you use IntelliJ IDEA as your IDE, I wouldn't recommend the latter, because you have to open three separate windows to edit them, and it's inconvenient.